# Ionic2 or Angular2 http request on interval

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, ionic2, angular2-http

I am trying to create a data service that pulls data from my API every set number of seconds and returns two Observables of the two different data types that the API returns. I am new to Observables so any help would be greatly appreciated.

My API returns a two arrays of json objects (ex `{'Data1':[array of data objects], 'Data2':[array of data objects]}`). Can I do something similar to this?

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService {
  data: any = null;
  dataType1: DataType1Model[] = [];
  dataType2: DataType2Model[] = [];
  service: Observable;

  constructor(public http: Http) {}

  start() {
    this.service = Observable.interval(10000)
      .flatMap(() => {
        this.http.get('url')
            .map(res => res.json())
            .subscribe(data => {
              this.data = data;
              this.processData1(this.data.Data1);
              this.processData2(this.data.Data2);
            });
        })
      .subscribe()
  }

  stop(){
    this.service.unsubscribe()
  }

  getData1() {
    return this.dataType1
  }

  getData2() {
    return this.dataType2
  }
}
```

Then in my component I can just import the DataService and call `data1 = DataService.getData1()`?

Will that call be an observable that will continue to update the data on the 10sec interval when the http request triggers? Again, I am new to observables, so sorry if this is totally wrong.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Service module will be something like this

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService {
  constructor(private http : Http) { }

  // Uses http.get() to load a single JSON file
  getData() : Observable<DataType1Model[]> {
      return Observable.interval(10000)
                       .flatMap(this.http.get('url')
                       .map((res:Response) => res.json()));
  }
}
```

And your Component should be like this-

```
@Component({
  selector: 'Selector',
  template:  "Template",
  providers:[
    DataService,

  ]
})
export class DataComponent implements OnInit{
  dataItem: DataType1Model[]  ;

  constructor(private _itemData:DataService ) { }

  getData(){
    this._itemData.getData()
    .subscribe(
      // the first argument is a function which runs on success
    (data:DataType1Model[]) => {
       this.dataItem = data;
     },
     // the second argument is a function which runs on error
     err => console.error(err),
     // the third argument is a function which runs on completion
     () => console.log('done loading data')

    );
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('hello `Item` component');
    this.getData();
  }

  stop(){
     _itemData.getData()
    .unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Call stop when you want to unsubscribe.

Comment: You are subscribing to a cold Observable multiple times (at least twice extraneously), `stop` is only unsubscribing from one of them.

Answer (score 1):

One problem with your approach is that when you call `getData1()` or `getData2()` there is no guarantee that data has already been received.

I also don't see where you call `start()`.

I think calling `subscribe(...)` on `this.http.get(...)...` is a mistake. `flatMap()` does the subscription by itself. It expects an `Observable` not a `Subscription` but when you call `subscribe()` a `Subscription` is what you get. To fix it replace the inner `subscribe` to `do` (and ensure the `do` operator is imported) or move the code from `subscribe` to the `map`.